# Redirect One Page to http instead of https

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

I have my .htaccess file like below for force https to all my pages.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R,L]
```

its working fine as per my requirements. Now I want exclude https for one of my page called demo.html
I do not want https for it.
its need

```
http://example.net/demo.html
```

instead of

```
https://example.net/demo.html
```

Comment: Do you _not_ want that page to get redirected to https, or do you want that page to get redirected to http while all other pages use https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `RewriteCond` condition for it.

Check the below code :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make that in same number of lines like this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^demo\.html$  https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

If that is OK , change `R` to `R=301` to get permanent redirection because `R` alone will be considered as `R=302` and that temporary redirection .